# Continuity of identity map between normed linear space.

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $f\in C[0, 1]$ and define $$\|f\|_p=(\int|f|^p dt) ^{\frac{1}{p}}, p=1, 2$$ Let $V_p$ be the space $C[0, 1]$ with norm $\|•\|$, then which of the following options are correct?

$1.$ the identity map is continuous from $V_1$ to $V_2$.

$2.$ the identity map is continuous from $V_2$ to $V_1$.

$3.$ the identity map is an isomorphism between $V_1$ and $V_2$.

I am unable to find constant $K$ or $L$ for  $\int |f|\leq K(\int |f|^2 dt) ^{\frac{1}{2}}$ or $(\int |f|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq L(\int |f| dt)$ as constants are changing with function $f$ . Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Hint: you can relate $\int |f|$ to $\int |f|^2$ by using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality with a suitable $g$.

Comment: @lan i tried by taking second function as $1$ but what about second inequality? Thank you.

Comment: @Ian $\int |f.1|\leq \|f\|_2\|1\|_2$ are saying this sir?

Answer (score 0):

As you say in the comments, as hinted by Ian, we have that $$\|f\|_1=\int_0^1|f(x)|dx=\int_0^1|f(x)|\cdot1dx\leq\big(\int_0^1|f(x)|^2dx\big)^{1/2}\cdot\big(\int_0^11^2dx\big)^{1/2}=\|f\|_2 $$

So the identity map $V_2\to V_1$ is continuous. On the other hand, the identity map $V_1\to V_2$ is not continuous: consider the functions $f_n(x)$, where $f_n(x)=n^{3/2}$ for $x\in[0,1/n^2]$, then $f_n$ descends linearly to $0$ in the interval $[1/n^2, 2/n^2]$ (so $f_n(2/n^2)=0$) and then $f_n$ is identically $0$. Note that
$$\int_0^1|f_n(x)|dx=n^{3/2}\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}+n^{3/2}\cdot\frac{1}{2n^2}=\frac{3}{2n^{1/2}}\to0 $$
so $f_n\to0$ in $\|\cdot\|_1$ while on the other hand
$$\big(\int_0^1|f_n(x)|^2dx\big)^{1/2}\geq\big(\int_0^{1/n^2}|f_n(x)|^2dx\big)^{1/2}=(n^3\cdot\frac{1}{n^2})^{1/2}=n^{1/2}\to\infty$$
so $(f_n)$ does not converge in $\|\cdot\|_2$. Thus only option B is correct.

edit: to see that $\|f_n\|_1\to0$ just draw these, their integrals are the area of a rectangle plus the area of a right triangle.

Comment: Who downvoted my answer and why? Downvoting without a specified reason is frowned upon in MSE.